# Cannot fully uninstall java

Tags: terminal, permission, java

I have disabled the system integrity protection via (in recovery mode)

```
csrutil disable
```

and now i am trying to fully delete java from my machine (it seems to block the reinstallation via ASDF)

```
 /usr/bin  sudo rm java
override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel restricted,compressed for java? y
rm: java: Read-only file system
 ✘  /usr/bin 
```

OS: macOS Monterey 12.0.1(21A559)

Any tips how to get access to these files?

Comment: What OS? Since Big Sur you can't play in the boot volume at all, it simply won't let you.

Comment: wait, but how was it written initially, i thought macos does not come with java preinstalled

Comment: I can't test whether it survives through upgrades, I don't have any Mac that was upgraded to Big Sur, only bought with it pre-installed.

Comment: Also the java in /usr/bin is not java but just a shim that works out where the java executable and runtime and compiler is. So haviong that file does not mean you have java. Running it gives you an error '$ java -h
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.'

Comment: I also did not upgrade. Got it like that. And where is that Java supposed to point at

Comment: It's supposed to point where it's currently pointing to.  Turn SIP back on, you should not have disabled it.  If you want a JVM installed, install one from Oracle.  Make sure you are compliant with the license, Java is not free-to-use software.

Comment: how can i find out where its pointing to? of course SIP is back on

Comment: `/usr/libexec/java_home --verbose` will list all the Java installations it can find, normally in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

Comment: You don't have to get an Oracle Java - there is OpenJDK and versions from Azul - plus I think Oracle might have chnaged the licence again

Comment: @mmmmmm Looks to me like typical Oracle... they made it more complicated.

Comment: @MarcWilson In this case it is Apple trying to be helpful and people not understanding it - it would help if Apple provided documentation up to 1990s standards

Comment: @mmmmmm You misunderstand.  I was referring to the licensing from Oracle, not the stub provided by Apple.